# Adding a suffix and a prefix to the word "ocean"

Tags: suffixes, is-it-a-word, prefixes, derivational-morphology

Is it possible to add a prefix to the word *ocean*?

Also, is it possible to add a suffix to it as well?

Comment: For suffixes, if you're looking for words that are already recorded in the dictionary, you can tack on an "-*ic*" ("*oceanic*") and multiple forms of "-*graphy*" ("*oceanography*","*oceanographer*", etc), as well as more specific, less flexible terms, like "*oceangoing*".  You can add any number of prefixes "*Suboceanic*", "*Transoceanic*", etc. The world's your oyster.  That said, if you can describe your **overall objective** in more detail, we might be able to suggest more suitable words.

Comment: The first question isn't off-topic, but the second is!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You've piqued my interest. Is it riddle? How can the first one be on- and the second off-topic? how is prefix OK but suffix not?

Comment: @Mitch Part of the ethos of the site is that _questions which are [readily] answerable by consulting a commonly available reference are off topic_. Looking up words _beginning_ with 'ocean' should present few problems.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is *yes*.  It is the nature of productive affixes that they can be freely applied to any word of the appropriate category to derive new words.

The longer answer depends on several things. One is just what you mean by prefixes and suffixes.  I’m going to assume that you do **not** mean merely to combine *ocean* with an existing, freestanding word to create a compound word such as occurs with *ocean-sea, world-ocean, ice-ocean, ocean-deep*.

Rather, I believe that you mean prefixes and suffixes that cannot stand on their own.  If so, then there is no reason that you cannot, provided that the affix chosen is one that can apply to words like *ocean*.  There are zillions of these combining forms, and so there are zillions of possibilities.

If your question is whether it is ever valid, or even just in this case, to apply both a prefix and a suffix to an existing word, then the answer is a resounding yes.   Consider:

- *faith* + *-ful* = *faithful*
- *faithful* + *-ly* = *faithfully*
- *un-* + *faithful* = *unfaithfully*

Just one example of a word derived from *ocean* using both a prefix and a suffix is *interoceanic*; many others are possible.

If you are thinking of a particular prefix or suffix, then I imagine that the reason you are asking this question is that you have looked up the resulting word in some dictionary or another, but failed to find the word you are looking for.

If so, then this might mean you are trying to use an affix in a way which that affix cannot reasonably be used in.   For example, you won’t find **y-oceant* in any dictionary, because those aren’t really affixes that lend themselves to *ocean*.

However, it might also mean that your word is not (yet?) common enough to be included in the dictionary you were checking for it in.  That doesn’t matter as to whether you can do it or not.  Putting units of language together in arbitrary combinations is central to what makes language, language.  This is true of individual words (“free morphemes”) and for combining forms (“bound morphemes”) alike.

So for example, even though I could find these in no dictionary, one could well imagine words like *mini-ocean, super-ocean, ur-ocean,* or even *über-ocean*. Those are all words that might someday occur, and indeed, may well have already occurred — somewhere and somewhen.

This only works for what are called “productive” affixes, a word that means they can be used at will to create any which word the coiner desires.

However, many prefixes and suffixes are no longer productive in English, which means you don’t get to do this with them anymore even though people once did so.  If you try to use an affix that is no longer productive, people might not know what you meant by it.  But if it is, they should.

No dictionary in existence ever lists all possible derived words, not only because their meaning in the case of productive affixes should be clear to any native speaker who reads them, but more importantly because the combinatoric explosion of possibilities would make listing all possibilities impossible.

Here, though, are some of the words mentioned by the OED which were derived by adding a prefix, suffix, or both to the word *ocean*:

- *cis-oceanic*
- *interocean*
- *interoceanic*
- *mid-ocean*
- *mid-oceanic*
- *oceanaria*
- *oceanarium*
- *oceanaut*
- *oceaned*
- *oceanet*
- *oceanful*
- *oceanic*
- *oceanicity*
- *oceanite*
- *oceanity*
- *oceanization*
- *oceanless*
- *oceanly*
- *oceanographer*
- *oceanographic*
- *oceanographical*
- *oceanographically*
- *oceanography*
- *oceanological*
- *oceanologist*
- *oceanology*
- *oceanward*
- *oceanwards*
- *oceanways*
- *oceanwise*
- *terr-oceanic*
- *transocean*
- *trans-oceanic*

This is only a sampling;  please feel free to create your own.  Several of the words listed above the OED calls “nonce-words”, which means they were created on the fly for one particular use, but whose use never really caught fire and spread to other authors.  Many words like this exist in English, and it is the nature of language that we can create what words we will as need arises.

Comment: Oh, "oceanful"; that's quite poetic.  I need to use that somehow.  BTW, I personally would exclude hyphenated words (like "*mid-oceanic*" and "*cis-oceanic*") from consideration, for the same reasons you excluded compound words (e.g. "*ice-ocean*", "*world-ocean*").

Comment: @DanBron Hyphenation is immaterial, and different writers use the hyphen differently. *Cisatlantic* and *cis-Atlantic* are the same word. Just look at *transocean* versus *trans-oceanic*.  It makes no sense to keep one and discard the other.  Plus each could be written the other way around.

Comment: @DanBron I guess you missed my point.  There is no end of words that can be equally well spelled *X-Y* and *XY*, plus some that also admit *X Y*.  Those are all the same word, because hyphenation is never forbidden nor required; it is simply a matter of style preference and acceptance. All four of *transocean, trans-ocean, transoceanic,* and *trans-oceanic* exist in the wild. Moreover, UK publishers are much more apt to retain the hyphen than North American publishers are in the very same word.  It makes no difference: those are still the same word with or without the hyphen.

Comment: Your views are not the only ones, though you rarely accept that others may be preferable, or acknowledge them only dismissively. Here is a fairer overview of the situation from [about education](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/noncewordterm.htm): "Sometimes 'nonce-formation' is restricted to linguistically irrelevant, quirky stylistic 'novelties'; sometimes it is seen as fully representative of the system of word-formation defining 'possible words.'"
(Pavol Štekauer and Rochelle Lieber, Handbook of Word-Formation. Springer, 2005)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I must be missing your point (which seems unnecessarily argumentative, and that may be the cause of my distraction). I don't see how your cited article conflicts with tchrist's inputs on the subject of nonce formation. It looks like unnecessary hair-splitting to me, but that could be a byproduct of trying to be concise. Maybe you can elaborate here in comments or in an answer also addressing the OP's question. What am I missing from your comment?

Comment: @Jim I'm referring to the statement ' “productive” affixes, a word that means they can be used at will to create any which word the coiner desires.' I've placed a question addressing whether this statement is true, or whether the word 'productive' is being used here with a sense which is unlicensed. The use of  'highly productive affixes', 'slightly productive affixes', and 'no longer productive' affixes in say academic articles indicates, I'm convinced, that this is the case.

Comment: I'm suggesting improvements: ' “productive” affixes, a word that means they can be used at will to create any which word the coiner desires' gives the impression that all linguists agree that adding an affix to a base word always results in another valid word. But [morphologist J Hay](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FQL9Ka9RBo4C&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22fairly+productive%22+affix&source=bl&ots=lD58pWs0lw&sig=rlRuRJJFr_geBUWQVJUrnEaSarQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Dxv5U53jBIfeaPT4gNgD&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22fairly%20productive%22%20affix&f=false) writes: 'For example -ful is a fairly productive affix'.